# Only insert new rows in SQLIte with pandas to_sql()

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I've got a dataframe in Pandas and I want to export the dataframe to sqlite with the pandas function to_sql(), the problem I've got is that function only admit remplace or append values, and I can not export just by inserting new rows.

to_sql() function:

```
if_exists : {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’

How to behave if the table already exists.

    fail: Raise a ValueError.
    replace: Drop the table before inserting new values.
    append: Insert new values to the existing table.
```

Is there an option to do that?